# Kotlin type auto boxing vs primitive

Tags: kotlin

```
class Remember private constructor() {

  private var data: ConcurrentMap<String, Any> = ConcurrentHashMap()

  private fun <T> saveValue(key: String, value: T): Remember {
    data[key] = value
    return this
  }

  private fun <T> getValue(key: String, clazz: Class<T>): T? {
    val value = data[key]
    var castedObject: T? = null


    //Failed here
    if (clazz.isInstance(value)) {
        castedObject = clazz.cast(value)
    }

    return castedObject
  }

  fun putInt(key: String, value: Int): Remember {
    return saveValue(key, value)
  }

  fun getInt(key: String, fallback: Int): Int {
    val value = getValue(key, Int::class.java)
    return value ?: fallback
  }

}
```

When I `putInt(key, 123)`, `123` is autoboxed to `java.lang.Integer`. When I get value from the `Map`, how do I compare `value` typed `Any` with `Class<T>` in which T is `Int:class.java` in this case? Currently, `clazz.isInstance(value)` always fails. It works if this class is written in Java

Comment: Does calling `getValue(key, Integer::class.java)` work?

Comment: I didn't try yet. It probably works.

Answer (score -1):

I think that's not kotlin but Java. Map only accepts Object type. So the primitive type will be autoboxed to put in a Map. So value returns from Map is alway Object.

Comment: I agreed. How do check `Object` is type Class<T> in which T is `Int:class.java`

Comment: Wrong. First of all, `Map` is just an interface that does not store or return values. The Kotlin version of the `Map` interface is capable of handling `Int` type as it is written in Kotlin. The `Map` implementation the OP uses, `ConcurrentHashMap`, as well as the interface, `ConcurrentMap` are written in Java and have no duplicate in Kotlin hence cannot handle Kotlin's `Int` type nor Java primitives like `int`, which Kotlin's `Int` type translate to